# Why can't I set the value of this radio button with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have some javascript as follows.  It fires when a user selects a radio button.  If the value of the button is 'board', it retrieves some data via ajax, and populates the display area.

```
if($('input:radio[name=switch]:checked').val() == 'board') {
    $.get('/content/board/id/' + $('#org-id').val() + '/format/html', function(data){
        $('div#display-area').html(data);
        $('input:radio[name=switch]').val('board');
    });                        
}
```

The radio buttons which trigger the event are named 'switch' and they are replaced in the data which is retrieved via ajax.  Therefore, after the display area has been updated with the new html, I need to set the value back to 'board'.

When I introduce this line of code though it stops working - the ajax will execute correctly the first time, but not thereafter.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you want to do with `$('input:radio[name=switch]').val('board');`

Comment: WHich event contains this code? Can you show that piece too

Comment: If you want to check the radio button with value `board` use $('input:radio[name=switch][value="board"]').prop('checked', true);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the line `$('input:radio[name=switch]').val('board');` is not working

Try

```
$('input:radio[name=switch][value="board"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Nice one Arun, thanks.  Any idea why my original approach didn't work?